# Get written data per day on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions

I want to graph how much data is written inside my MediaWiki per day to graph the activity. The exact amount of bytes is not important, I just want to see the relative change per day/month/year.

I only found the Statistics Log extension which is not maintained since 1.15.

Any solution via `extension/api/mysql` would be great. If I can get the value of the bytes/chars or anything else by any method I can do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an easy answer. But you can get started with "RecentChanges" table and related API: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:RecentChanges

```
rc_old_len
This field stores the size, in bytes, of previous revision's text. 

rc_new_len
This field stores the size, in bytes, of the current revision's text.
```

Reference: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Recentchanges_table#rc_new_len

Comment: Thanks, with this info I could solve it via mysql: SELECT SUM( ABS( rc_new_len - rc_old_len ) ) FROM recentchanges WHERE rc_timestamp LIKE "20160415%";

Comment: Note that `ABS( rc_new_len - rc_old_len )` is the length change, not the number of bytes changed (ie. if I change `foo` to `bar` in the text, the number of bytes changed will be 3 but `ABS( rc_new_len - rc_old_len )` will be 0). I don't know of any better metric that's readily available, though.

Comment: On the more general (and more difficult) topic of measuring work, https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Measuring_value-added has some information (although again, nothing readily usable).